# Connect redux reducers with reduxform in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, next.js

I'm trying to combine reduxForm with my custom reducers inside nextjs with no luck. I'm using this as initial working example: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-redux-wrapper/store.js

When I add reduxForm according to their docs, I get error: `Cannot read property 'source' of undefined` , which means that store doesn't even exist.

How my `store.js` looks now:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import axios from 'axios';
import getRootUrl from '../lib/api/getRootUrl';

const initialState = {
  user: 0,
  agent: 0,
};

export const actionTypes = {
  FETCH_USER: 'FETCH_USER',
  USER_AGENT: 'USER_AGENT',
};

// REDUCERS
const authReducer = (state = { user: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_USER': return { user: action.payload };
    default: return state;
  }
};
const agentReducer = (state = { agent: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_AGENT': return { agent: action.payload };
    default: return state;
  }
};

// ACTIONS
export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const ROOT_URL = getRootUrl();
  const resUser = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/api/current_user`);
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.FETCH_USER, payload: resUser.data });
};

export const getUserAgent = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const ROOT_URL = getRootUrl();
  const resAgent = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/api/useragent`);
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.USER_AGENT, payload: resAgent.data });
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authReducer,
  agentReducer,
  formReducer,
});

export const initStore = (newState = initialState) => createStore(
  rootReducer,
  newState,
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)),
);
```

Last working example. I tried to combine with-redux-wrapper syntax with reduxForm docs. reduxForm action and reducer don't work here: https://github.com/neone35/rearn/blob/master/server/store.js

How can I combine these two to use reduxForm inside my component containing Field components?

Comment: Now if I use reducer separately, for example only 'authReducer' instead of rootReducer, it works perfectly. Whats wrong? https://pastebin.com/TMEAgmTM

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem after reading more of this documentation:

- https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state
- https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers

Also, I've logged out console to see what props my component is receiving to resolve problem faster.

How my `store.js` looks now:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import axios from 'axios';
import getRootUrl from '../lib/api/getRootUrl';

const initialState = {
  user: '0',
  agent: '0',
};

export const actionTypes = {
  FETCH_USER: 'FETCH_USER',
  USER_AGENT: 'USER_AGENT',
};

// REDUCERS
const authReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_USER:
      return action.payload || false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const agentReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.USER_AGENT:
      return action.payload || false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: authReducer,
  agent: agentReducer,
  form: formReducer,
});

// ACTIONS
export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const ROOT_URL = getRootUrl();
  const resUser = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/api/current_user`);
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.FETCH_USER, payload: resUser.data });
};

export const getUserAgent = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const ROOT_URL = getRootUrl();
  const resAgent = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/api/useragent`);
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.USER_AGENT, payload: resAgent.data });
};

export const initStore = (newInitialState = initialState) =>
  createStore(rootReducer, newInitialState, compose(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)));
```

I separated all my **reducers** into functions which initialize state to null (because **initStore** gets passed zeros, and **preloadedState (initialState)** always has priority). I return raw value from **action creator** (without object) and it gets passed straight to **combineReducers** (which creates object) which is **rootReducer** inside **createStore**.